# VBS to Launch Custom Firefox Window and URL

Tags: firefox, vbscript

I have been mashing up some script to launch a portable version of Firefox with an URL linked to Webcams.  My objective is to have 2 scripts using the same FF.exe but going to 2 different URLS/IP's.  I am trying to rescrict the browser function by removing scroll bars.menus and status so only the webcam controls and view can be seen.

This is the current code but I seem to have made an error as now the URL is not displaying, only the default on launch.  The sizing is perfect.

```
dim wshshell

FirefoxProfile = "Profile"
FirefoxPath = "C:\ADMIN\FF\FF.exe"
webappurl = "http://Domain.com"
Height = "870"
Width = "920"

Set wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshshell.run """" & FirefoxPath & """ -P """ & FirefoxProfile & """ -Height """ & Height & """ -Width """ & Width & "" & webappurl

Set wshshell = Nothing
wscript.quit
```

Any help that you can provide or just a nudge in the right direction would be most appreciated.  This is something else that I have found so maybe this could be used, Unfortunately I don't think that on it's own it's any use.

```
window.open('Domain.com',null,"height=100px,width=100px,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0");
```

Working code :

```
dim wshshell

Function qq(str)
qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

FirefoxProfile = "Profile"
FirefoxPath = "C:\ADMIN\FF\FF.exe"
webappurl = "172.22.111.8"
Height = "700"
Width = "920"
Status ="0"
Toolbar = "0"
Menubar = "0"

Set wshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshshell.run qq(FirefoxPath) & " -P " & qq(FirefoxProfile) _
& " -status " & qq(status) & " -Toolbar " & qq(toolbar) & " -menubar " & qq(menubar) _
& " -Height " & qq(Height) & " -Width " & qq(Width) _
& " " & webappurl

Set wshshell = Nothing
wscript.quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your problem lies here:

```
wshshell.run ... & """ -Width """ & Width & "" & webappurl
```

The last `""` in that instruction is just an empty string when you probably need a closing double quote followed by a space:

```
wshshell.run ... & """ -Width """ & Width & """ " & webappurl
```

I usually recommend using a quoting function to avoid quotefusion:

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

'...

wshshell.run qq(FirefoxPath) & " -P " & qq(FirefoxProfile) _
  & " -Height " & qq(Height) & " -Width " & qq(Width) _
  & " " & webappurl
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ansgar for soving my problem and also suggesting a good point with using a quoting function. I was getting a little parenthisis dizzy. The working script is now this for anybody that is looking for a similar thing. The only problem I have now is finding the correct switches for FF to everything but the window itself. After some looking around I may have to find a different browser that has a complete selection of commandline arguments. 
_Updated OP with code_