# vbscript to get the files in a format from ftp with today's modified date

Tags: batch-file, scripting, vbscript, ftp

I have a requirement to get the files in a specified format from a ftp using vbscript. Can any one help me on this.

I have to get files with name format `VarList12DDMMYYYY******.csv`, `VarList10DDMMYYYY******.csv`, `VarList11DDMMYYYY******.csv`, `VarList22DDMMYYYY******.csv` where 12,10,11,22 which will be there in everyday file and DDMMYYYY is today's date and `*****` is the HHMMSSMS which is hour, minute, second and millisecond at which file is generated from the ftp.

Daily files will be generated in ftp at different times so HHMMSSMS would vary daily. So I would be happy if any one can help me with vbscript to download above 4 files everyday.

I thought it could be done using the date modified, but could not find any relevant one when i have searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288199/1630171) to a similar question. You just need to modify the filename pattern, e.g. like this:

```
timestamp = Right("0" & Day(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Year(Now)
.WriteLine "mget VarList12" & timestamp & "*.csv"
.WriteLine "mget VarList10" & timestamp & "*.csv"
.WriteLine "mget VarList11" & timestamp & "*.csv"
.WriteLine "mget VarList22" & timestamp & "*.csv"
```

Comment: Hi, I am not getting output and also no error is generated, I worked out so many times, but atlast a cmd file opens and closes down, please see the entire code

Comment: Dim objOutStream, objFSO, objShell Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") Set objOutStream = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\605932928\desktop\STB Messaging\ftp_downloadcmds.txt",True) sDwnLdSite="xx.xx.xx.xx" timestamp = Right("0" & Day(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Year(Now) With objOutStream .WriteLine "USER USERNAME" ' USERNAME .WriteLine "password" ' Password  .WriteLine "prompt n"
    .WriteLine "mget VarList11" & timestamp & "*.csv"   .WriteLine "mget VarList10" & timestamp & "*.csv"
    .WriteLine "mget VarList12" & timestamp & "*.csv"

Comment: .WriteLine "mget VarList22" & timestamp & "*.csv"
    .WriteLine "quit"
    .Close
     End With
wscript.sleep 20000

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
InputCmdFile = "C:\Users\605932928\desktop\STB Messaging\ftp_downloadcmds.txt"
objShell.run "%comspec% /c FTP -n -i -s:" &InputCmdFile& " " &sDwnLdSite &""

Comment: Please don't post code comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: The problem is most likely due to the space in the path to your FTP command file. Put the path between double quotes (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15255895/1630171)).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one.. it will work

```
FTPDwnLdCmdLine = FTPDwnLdCmdLine &"binary" &VbCrlf
FTPDwnLdCmdLine = FTPDwnLdCmdLine &"prompt n" &VbCrlf
 FTPDwnLdCmdLine = FTPDwnLdCmdLine &"mget " &chr(34)&"AccountsList10"&strDay&""&strMonth&""&Year(date)&"******.csv"&chr(34)&VbCrlf

FTPDwnLdCmdLine = FTPDwnLdCmdLine &"binary" &VbCrlf
FTPDwnLdCmdLine = FTPDwnLdCmdLine &"mget " &chr(34)&"AccountsList11"&strDay&""&strMonth&""&Year(date)&"******.csv"&chr(34)&VbCrlf
```

In the similar manner try it for your accounts...cheers...Manjunath cherukuru